# Decomposition of Non-Trivial Zeroes of Riemann Zeta Function (Product of Integrals)

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In my search for a solution to the Riemann Hypothesis, I entered the first non-trivial zero to the Zeta function into the product of integrals definition; specifically the Gamma Function. Using Wolfram Alpha and a 3 digit approximation of the first zero, I separated the integral of x^(n*i-(1/2)e^(-x), which equals 0i+0 for n=14.132... on 0 to infinity, into an imaginary component and a real component. The results surprised me, the integral of x^(-1/2)*e(-x) on 0 to infinity evaluated as square root of pi. I tried integrating the imaginary portion, x^(14.132i) on limits of 0 to infinity, but the integral does not converge! I’m surprised that when you integrate the real and imaginary portions separately, neither evaluates as a zero value, though they do evaluate to 0i + 0 when the integrals are separated. 
Can anyone shed some light as to why this occurs? Perhaps this observation regarding the changes in both of the component (real and imaginary) values that occur as a result of the decomposition of a complex (non-trivial) zero of the Gamma function into integrals of  Real and Imaginary terms can lend itself to proving the hypothesis?

Comment: $\Gamma(1/2+i 14.1 ) = \int_0^\infty x^{1/2+i 14.1 -1}e^{-x}dx=a+ib$ where $a=\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2} \cos( 14.1 \log x)e^{-x}dx$ and $b=\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2} \sin( 14.1 \log x)e^{-x}dx$. Nobody said $\Gamma(1/2+i 14.1 )=0$. You can use $ \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1}{e^x+1}dx = \Gamma(s)(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ to check the non-trivial zeros.

Comment: $\Gamma$ has no zeroes, only poles!